# How to set css image url in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am using this code for making background image fixed but image url is not working can you tell me what I am missing.

code is written in my view file :

```
html { 
     background: url(<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/img.jpg) no-repeat  center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Why I am getting "304 error" on all these files? I'm using this code to link these files:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
 <link href=" <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href=" <?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: what was error or problem

Comment: try this, background: url(../assets/images/img.jpg) no-repeat  center center fixed;

Comment: try with this `background: url(../assets/images/img.jpg)no-repeat center;`

Comment: background image is stretched i want to make it fixed

Comment: @Bhargav i tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Where is your assets folder?

Comment: asset is in codeigniter's main directory while file containing this code is in view folder. directory structure is like this:
ci/
asset/images/img.jpg
   ,application/view/codefile

Answer (score 3):

you are missing `""`() double quotes.

Use this css for fixed background

```
body{
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-image: url(<?php echo base_url();?>./image.jpg);
}
```

or else ,
try using this.

```
background-image: url("../image.jpg");
```

Comment: body is used in css because body holds the backgound image

Comment: note this `<?php echo base_url();?>`. will not work in .css

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
<div class="profile-pic-feadback" style="background-image:url(<?php echo base_url('images/user.png') ?>)"></div>
```

you have to used background-image. then it will work. I used this way only.

Comment: have you try to give this as inline css. I was having same error. so put all image css code in css file and only setting image url path code as a inline css. and it work me.

Comment: Can you give me the whole code. Are you sure image is stored into the same path

Comment: See i have updated my answered so you understand in more better way.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your css file is in assets folder

```
application

assets

assets > css > example.css

assets > images

system 

index.php
```

Then try this in the CSS file

```
body {
  background: url('../images/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

> **Of course make sure you have set the base url in the config.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

Comment: Sir I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, I have updated my question can you please check it I think because of that error it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {

background-image: url('../assests/images/img.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

}
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting code should have some text explaining what needs to be done etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way:

```
html { 
     background-image: url('<?= base_url("assets/images/img.jpg");?>') no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

But I have to say that [wolfgang1983's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571016/6401175) is a better practice. Avoid using CSS in your views.